# Modificar archivo BR.java - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola buenas noches comunidad StackOverflow tengo un problema quiero modificar el archivo BR.java en Android Studio y no me deja me sale el mensaje "Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited"

La primera imagen es una que esta sin modificar que solo tiene una variable la que viene por defecto

```
public static final int _all = 0;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda imagen es de una imagen ya modificada y tiene 3 variables

```
public static final int _all = 0;
public static final int model = 1;
public static final int position = 2;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.
Alguien sabe como modificar el archivo BR.java?
Saludos.

Comment: Y, ¿por qué ese archivo está en la carpeta `build`?

Comment: Es autogenerado que se compila automáticamente del data binding en Android.

Comment: Esos archivos no pueden borrarse directamente. ¿Por qué quieres borrarlo? Si es por una situación de error, o porque ya no lo necesitas, corrige el error en el proyecto o elimina del proyecto el archivo que lo genera y luego haz un Clean and Build del proyecto.

Comment: No quiero borrarlo quiero agregarle nuevos parametros como vez en la primera figura hay 1 y en la segunda figura hay 3 quiero modificar el archivo BR.java para así utilizarlo en el RecyclerView. Quiero usar BR.model y BR.position en el RecyclerView.

Comment: Tienes que modificar el archivo del proyecto que tiene relación con BR.java (en la parte del proyecto), como te dice claramente el mensaje, **no puedes modificar archivos auto-generados**.

Comment: ¿Cual es ese archivo que debo modificar? Eso es lo que quiero saber.

Comment: Los archivos de arriba, que son los del proyecto en sí. Los que tienen error están marcados en rojo. Por ejemplo en `view` tienes un archivo con error. Corrije lo que tengas que corregir ahí y luego haz un Clean and Build y los archivos autogenerados se crearán de nuevo. Es el proyecto donde debes modificar tus archivos, no en la parte de auto-generados.

Comment: Ok, pero ¿cual es ese archivo específico?

Comment: Si observas, a la derecha del directorio `java` en el que intentas modificar, dice `(generated)`. Esos archivos se generan solos, no debes nunca tocar ningún archivo de esa carpeta `java`.

Comment: ¿No lo ves con una raya roja debajo? Se llama **`ReclycerViewCouponsAdapter`** y está en la carpeta **`view`** de tu proyecto. Los archivos que tú debes modificar cuando quieras cambiar algo tienen que ser esos, los del nodo donde está tu carpeta `view` y las demás carpetas de ese nodo, que no se ve entero en la captura de pantalla.

Comment: Si ya lo arregle ese, y lo compile, compilo bien pero igual no se modifica el BR.java.

Comment: Como ya dije, **en tus archivos de proyecto** es donde tienes que cambiar las definiciones de las variables u objetos que quieres modificar. ¿Qué archivo de tu proyecto se relaciona con `BR.java`? Es ese archivo el que debes modificar (en el proyecto) no en la parte auto-generada.

Comment: Ya sé es el item_requerimiento, el item del recycler view ahí en <data></data> le tienes que poner las variables position y model y de ahí compilar y automáticamente te aparecerá las variables en el BR. Ya lo hice.

Comment: ¿Ya funciona o aún no?

Comment: Si ya funcionó. Gracias!

Comment: Me alegro. Pues para la próxima, no toques los archivos auto-generados, debes corregir las cosas en tu proyecto y hacer Clean and Build y todo se generará de nuevo con los nuevos valores / contenidos.

Answer (score 1):

Si puedes modificar los archivos que se encuentran dentro de `/build` pero estos no guardaran los cambios despues de generar tu proyecto.

De hecho el archivo `BuildConfig.java` es un archivo generado a partir de valores que se encuentran dentro del archivo `Build.gradle`,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes modificar los valores dentro de un archivo generado pero estos seran sobreescrvitos cuando se genere la aplicacion.

**Debes unicamente editar los archivos que se encuentran dentro de `/app/java`**